# Insert dictionary values if keys present in cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file that I've imported through Pandas with a column called 'Keywords'. Each cell in the column has a various number of keywords such as Confident, Dark, Mysterious, etc.

```
    Keywords
0   Confident, Mysterious
1   Confident
2   Dark
```

I have a dictionary of synonyms to these keywords

```
    terms = {'Confident': 'Cool', 'Dark': ['Gloomy', 'Negative', 'Haunting'], 'Mysterious': 'Mystical'}
```

I'm trying to write something that will look for the dictionary keys in the Keywords column, and add the corresponding synonyms (values) to the cell, so the final product becomes:

```
    Keywords
0   Confident, Cool, Mysterious, Mystical
1   Confident, Cool
2   Dark, Gloomy, Negative, Haunting
```

I've tried a few things like:

```
    df['Keywords'].map(terms)
```

Or:

```
    df['Keywords'].apply(lambda l: [terms[e] for e in l])
```

...but no luck yet. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be to change the dictionary values to be the same type. This will make it easier to populate the results later on. Something like:

```
terms = {
    'Confident': ['Cool'],
    'Dark': ['Gloomy', 'Negative', 'Haunting'],
    'Mysterious': ['Mystical']
}
```

Given that, we then need to return the list of synonyms and original words.

```
def mapper(row):
    # Replace all the whitespace
    blanks = row['Keywords'].replace(' ', '')
    # Split based on commas
    s = blanks.split(',')

    # Find all synonyms
    res = []
    for keyword in s:
        res.append(keyword)
        if keyword in terms:
            for synonym in terms[keyword]:
                res.append(synonym)
    return res
```

And once we have this, we can then call df.apply.

```
# This is what I think your dataframe looks like
d = {'Keywords': ['Confident, Mysterious', 'Confident', 'Dark']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
new_df = df.apply(mapper, axis=1)
```

Calling with axis = 1 means that we go through rows, not columns.